# How to get the size of a tile in map in meters

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, distance

Hi there I am currently working on geographical-based program and wondering how to get size of a tile.

Let's say that I have Googleplex's coordinate that located in latitude 37.4219999 and longitude -122.0862462.
With 15 zoom level, I can get the x is 5271 and y 12706. Here's the picture

[image]

So my question is, how to get the size of tile from left to right in meters? And how do I get the specific coordinate bounds of the tile (left-top, right-top, left-bottom, right-bottom)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OpenStreetMap wiki page on "Slippy map tilenames"](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) shows the relevant formulas as pseudocode and in various programming languages. For calculating a tile's coordinate bounds, you want "Tile numbers to lon./lat.". To get the bottom and right borders, just add 1 to your tile coordinate in that dimension.

That page also has a [table](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution%20and%20Scale) with the m/px, i.e. meters per pixel values for each of the common zoom levels. Pay attention to the hint about multiplying these values by `cos(latitude)`, as they depend on how far you are from the equator.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that. Finally I calculated the difference between x, y and x + 1, y.